# Can I use @OneToMany(mappedBy="...") in @MappedSuperclass?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I recently read an [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) about the best way to map a `@OneToMany` relationship with JPA and Hibernate by Vlad Mihalcea. I would like to use the described mappings for my classes as well, but my referencing side must be a MappedSuperclass*.

Let's say I have these two classes:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
public abstract class Bookable {

    private Set<Review> reviews;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "bookable", orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<Review> getReviews() {
        return reviews;
    }
}
```

`Bookable` represents the superclass for several entities that can be booked and also has some other fields which were omitted for brevity. My question here is: what can I use for the `mappedBy` as there will be no `bookable` table in the database? There are different subtypes, so how do I set the subclasses to be the referencing side?

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
public class Review extends HasId {

    private Long id;
    private Bookable bookable;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @JoinColumn(name = "bookable_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Bookable getBookable() {
        return bookable;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // Left out for brevity
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // Left out for brevity
    }
}
```

In the `Review` class several fields were omitted for brevity as well.

With the code above I run into a

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: Review.main_bookable in SportsFacility.reviews
```

* When `Bookable` was an Entity, certain foreign key colums were duplicated to the tables of the subclasses and would always be null for the subclasses. E.g. a vendor (referencing side) couldn't access it's sports facilities (owning side) because the vendor_id would be null in the `sports_facility` table while only being set correctly in the `bookable` table. That's why I had to switch to MappedSuperclass.

Comment: What is your table structure of your `Review` class ?

Comment: @KenChan why is this relevant? I can't generate the SQL, that's why I posted this question!

Comment: because I don't quite get why you mean when you explain why you switch to the MappedSuperclass . Suppose there two `Bookable` things (let say `restaurant` and `sportFacility`) , then each bookable has their own table and in the `review` table , there are two FK columns called `restaurant_id` and `sport_facility_id` to referencing all bookable ?

Comment: Can't do that. You can extend an `Entity` so you can make bookable an entity.